# Get themes's images path in WordPress Multisite

Tags: theme-development, multisite

I have installed a WordPress multisite subdomain network site, so for some blog, it can be accessed with this address

```
http://theme.example.com/blog
```

I tried to install theme, but it can't access all image used in the theme folder. Is there anythings i need to set up first? such as multisite settings or maybe using .htaccess?

Comment: Hi you are a little vague. What do you mean? Are you using get_bloginfo(). Refer to http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_bloginfo

Comment: the problem is some images loaded for theme is broken. i think it's the image path problem. can you point me out to the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessing a Theme's directory in a multisite environment is no different from a single-site environment:

- [`get_template_directory_uri()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory_uri) for stand-alone or parent Themes
- [`get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri) for child Themes

Please [ensure that the Theme has been *enabled*](http://codex.wordpress.org/Multisite_Network_Administration#Themes), either globally, or for the specific multisite network site.